# Identityserver post login url should be last state before logout in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

By Default when we log in using identity server it goes to default page that is domain/signin-oidc and then to default screen.

but i want that after person logs in we can decide dynamically where do we want to send our customer.

Like their is possibility that you were working on one page x and you were logged out because of session expiration then you should again be redirected after login to the same page x. but in current time it is redirected to default page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it looks like the question is more about the client than the identityprovider. it would be good to explain the whole picture. in general when a user really works with a page, the session should not expire at all. it would be better to think about sliding session at Identityserver and possibly refresh token at the client.